# R jsonlite - fromJSON always returns Error in open.connection?

Tags: r, shiny, jsonlite

Why do I always get the connection error with `fromJSON`? Sometimes it is fine. Most of time it is not.

```
> # Load json and other packages.
> library(jsonlite)
> 
> # Live server.
> server <- 'http://0.0.0.0:3000'
> # Stream 143
> key <- '9p06nngO2pcQM03nIJ71dLXNA1v'
> 
> # Retrieve json data from the data platform via the URLs.
> streams <- fromJSON(paste(server, '/output/streams', sep=""), flatten=TRUE)
```

Result:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server

If I try again:

```
> streams <- fromJSON(paste(server, '/output/streams', sep=""), flatten=TRUE)
```

Error:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") :    Server returned nothing (no
>   headers, no data)

But the server is fine. It is up and running.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Or any other better and more reliable package for getting the json data from the server?

Comment: You are trying to get a JSON from `http://0.0.0.0:3000/output/streams`. It's a pretty strange url. Is there a server up and running somewhere? What is its IP? Maybe you should replace `0.0.0.0` with the actual server IP.

Comment: it is a dummy URL.

Comment: you can try to access the server with this `http://139.162.208.52:3000/output/stream?public_key=9p06nngO2pcQM03nIJ71dLXNA1v` and you will see the problem with jsonlite

Comment: The first error seems to indicate that the server is not up (or that a connection can't be established for some reason). The second error indicates that the server got the request, but didn't return anything (and so there is nothing `jsonlite` can parse). The url you posted returns the text `stream not found`, which is not a valid JSON.

Comment: This is the server and it is up and running http://139.162.208.52:3000

Comment: try this again - http://139.162.208.52:3000/output/stream?public_key=9p06nngO2pcQM03nIJ71dLXNA1v

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is some special character in the `public_key` field. For instance:

```
Gurl<-"http://139.162.208.52:3000/output/stream?public_key=9p06nngO2pcQM03nIJ71dLXNA1v"
Burl<-"http://139.162.208.52:3000/output/stream?public_key=9p06nngO‌​2pcQM03nIJ71dLXNA1v"
#this seems to work
fromJSON(Gurl, flatten=TRUE)
#this doesn't
fromJSON(Burl, flatten=TRUE)
```

`Burl` and `Gurl` are only apparently the same:

```
Gurl==Burl
#[1] FALSE
```

You can inspect the `raw` content of the above urls (with `charToRaw`) and check the `Encoding` to spot the differences.

Comment: Sorry, I know what URL is not working now `http://139.162.208.52:3000/output/streams`

Answer (score -1):

Eg. Php, basic just get data from server by json_encode
What programming languages are u using? For back-end

Comment: It is R. Not PHP.