# R: json file from API on computer with company network

Tags: json, r, api, firewall

I am trying to make a script that will download a file from API official air quality control in Poland (http://powietrze.gios.gov.pl/pjp/content/api). The location on the server is:

```
URL  <- "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll"
```

The problem is I am working on remote server and company network, this maybe caused by firewall or proxy. I had similar problem with webscraping before, but solution from [rvest Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295686/rvest-error-in-open-connectionx-rb-timeout-was-reached) helped. Unfortunatly this time is not the case. I tried downloading the file:

```
URL  <- "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll"
File_name <- "tmp.csv"
download.file(URL, destfile = File_name, quiet=TRUE)
```

but later the file is unreadable (due to incomplete readTableHeader).
When I tried downloading a file in `.json` format as in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_json_files.htm and read it with `fromJSON`, I got `Error in fromJSON(file = File_name) : argument "txt" is missing, with no default`

I have also tried using `fromJSON(URL)` as sugested in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-apis.html, but i get error: `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Timeout was reached`. I changed `options(timeout= 4000000)`, but id did not help.

Also I tried `GET(URL)` as in https://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-apis-from-r-and-a-little-r-programming/, also with progress() and verbose() arguments as in [Can't use jsonlite in R to read json format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528321/cant-use-jsonlite-in-r-to-read-json-format-file)

## EDIT

As sugested by @Junhee Shin I have tried following methods:

- `wget` which worked for >5 min and did not produce anything
- `internal` coused error `Error in download.file(URL, destfile = File_name, method = "internal") :   cannot open URL 'http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll'
  In addition: Warning message: In download.file(URL, destfile = File_name, method = "internal") :   unable to connect to 'api.gios.gov.pl' on port 80.`
- `wininet` which worked (with error `Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' length unknown`, but `fromJSON` had an error `argument "txt" is missing, with no default`
- `libcurl` which crashed my R session twice
- `curl` coused error: `Warning messages:
  1: running command 'curl  "http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll"  -o "D:\magisterka\Wroclaw Open Data\tmp.json"' had status 127 
  2: In download.file(URL, destfile = File_name, method = "curl") :
  download had nonzero exit status`
- `auto` which worked (with error `Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' length unknown`, but `fromJSON` had an error `argument "txt" is missing, with no default`

## EDIT 2

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: try this. download.file(URL, File_name, 'wget')   download load method. "auto", "internal", "libcurl", "wget", "curl"

Comment: @JunheeShin I have tried it (and written in EDIT), but it did not work

Comment: I think it's a firewall issue as I had no problems using the fromJSON(URL) method. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528321/cant-use-jsonlite-in-r-to-read-json-format-file and hope it's helpful.

Comment: @TTR I have tried it, but error `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :   Timeout was reached` occured

Answer (score 0):

Here is another potential alternative solution :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll")
Sys.sleep(5)

page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
readHTMLTable(page_Content)
```

Here is another potential alternative solution :

```
library(pdftools)
library(pagedown)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
chrome_print("http://api.gios.gov.pl/pjp-api/rest/station/findAll",
             "C:\\...\\json_pdf.pdf")

text <- pdf_text("C:\\...\\json_pdf.pdf")
text <- paste0(text, collapse = "")
text <- str_remove_all(text, pattern = "\\r\\n")
result <- jsonlite::fromJSON(text)
```